# T-SQL How to sum columns into rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to produce a summary table from old records:

```
 Ref     Name   count11 count12     Name2   count21 count22     Name3     count31 count32 
========================================================================================
1        item1       2      0      item2       0      1         item3       120    0  
2        item1       32     3      item2       3      1         item3       3      5    
3        item1       0      2      item2       0      0         item3       0      5    
4        item1       12     1      item2       1      1         item3       1      1    
5        item1       0      0      item2       0      0         item3       0      0
```

Sum up the 'count' columns into this:

```
Ref     items       count1      count2
========================================
1       item1       46          6
2       item2       4           3
3       item3       124         11
```

How can I archive this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT tt.Ref, tt.items, SUM([count1]), SUM([count2])
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (1, [Name],  [count11], [count12]), 
              (2, [Name2], [count21], [count22]), 
              (3, [Name3], [count31], [count32]) 
     ) tt(Ref, items, [count1], [count2])
GROUP BY tt.Ref, tt.items;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually your answer is better and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

We can try doing a pivot query, but on a CTE which create a single logical column for all items:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Name, count11 AS count1, count12 AS count2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, count21, count22 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, count31, count32 FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    Name AS items,
    SUM(count1) AS count1,
    SUM(count2) AS count2
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Name
ORDER BY
    Name;
```

I omitted the `Ref` column, because the values in your expected output don't really have anything to do with the original data.  You could use `ROW_NUMBER` with some ordering, if you wanted a sequence in the output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the solution works quit well. If I have a datetime colume in ''yourTable'', how can I insert the WHERE datetime condition in CTE?

Comment: You would probably want to add the `WHERE` clause to each query in the union.

Comment: Thank you very much :)  and yes, you can ignore the `Ref` column